# Merge Sorting by using Queue in Java

Tags: java, arrays, queue, mergesort

```
public class NumberQueue {
    private int firstLoc=0;
    private int lastLoc=0;
    private int[] numArray = new int[MAXSIZE]; 
    public static final int MAXSIZE=100;

    public int getQsize() { 
        return (MAXSIZE+lastLoc-firstLoc) % MAXSIZE;
    }

    public boolean fullCheck() { 
        return (getQsize() == MAXSIZE-1);
    }

    public boolean emptyCheck() { 
        return (firstLoc == lastLoc); 
    }

    public int getValue(int loc) { 
        return numArray[loc];
    }   

    public int front() {
        return numArray[firstLoc]; 
    }

    public void remove() { 
        if (!emptyCheck()) 
            firstLoc = (firstLoc + 1) % MAXSIZE;
    }

    public int insert(int val) {
        if (fullCheck()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
          numArray[lastLoc] = val;
          lastLoc = (lastLoc +1) % MAXSIZE;
          return 0;
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        int i = firstLoc;
        while(i < lastLoc) {
            System.out.print(numArray[i]+" ");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
}


public class NumberQueueMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Create three queues
    NumberQueue S1 = new NumberQueue();
    NumberQueue S2 = new NumberQueue();
    NumberQueue S3 = new NumberQueue();

    //Get the array of queues       
    Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a series of number with a space between each value: ");       
    String str = S.nextLine();
    String[] arr = str.split(" ");
    int array[] = new int[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
    }

    //Put the array into the NumberQueues-S1.
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        S1.insert(array[i]);
    }

    //Merge Sort S1 
    int loc = -1;
    while(loc < (S1.getQsize()-1)) {
        do {
            S2.insert(S1.front());       
            S1.remove();                
            loc++;
        } while(S1.getValue(loc) < S1.getValue(loc+1) && loc < S1.getQsize()-1);
        S2.display(); 

        while(loc < S1.getQsize()-1) {
            do{
                S3.insert(S1.front());
                S1.remove();
                loc++;
        } while(S1.getValue(loc) < S1.getValue(loc+1) && loc < S1.getQsize()-1);
            S3.display();
        }

        while(!S2.emptyCheck() && !S3.emptyCheck()) {
            if(S2.front() > S3.front()) {
                S1.insert(S3.front());
                S3.remove();        
            } else if(S2.front()==S3.front()) {
                S1.insert(S2.front());
                S1.insert(S3.front());
                S2.remove();
                S3.remove();
            } else {
                S1.insert(S2.front());
                S2.remove();
            }
        }

        if (S2.emptyCheck()){
            int sizeS3 = S3.getQsize();
            for(int i = 0;i < sizeS3; i++){
                S1.insert(S3.front());
                S3.remove();
            }
        } else if(S3.emptyCheck()){
            int sizeS2 = S2.getQsize();
            for(int i = 0;i < sizeS2; i++) {
                S1.insert(S2.front());
                S2.remove();
            }
        }
    } 
    System.out.println();
    S1.display();
  }
```

}

**Output:**

> Enter a series of number with a space between each value:  3 5 7 2 3 5
>   11 34 12 10 15 18 3 12 17 22 12 18 25 22 30 3 5 7  2 3 5 11 34  2 3 5
>   11 34 12  2 3 5 11 34 12 10 15  18  3 12 17 22  12 18 25  22  30
>
> 2 3 3 5 5 7 11 34 12 10 15 3 12 17 18 22 12 18 25 22 30

**Question:**
Why it only sort each two queues next to each other, and just did once. I can't find out the place to fix it. Anyone helps me, please!!!

Comment: I don't see the need to add "android" tag. Don't you ?

Comment: I'd probably just google the algorithm.  Looks like you gave it a good effort, but this code is too messy to make sense of.

Comment: My professor wants us the write a merge sort by using queues and a given class, which is "class NumberQueue". Cannot find on Google.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I'd like to help you rephrase your question "Why it only sort each two queues next to each other, and just did onece. " It's quite unclear what you are asking. If you could explain what you mean by 'sorting two queues next to each other' or 'just did once' then we might be able to offer some more help.

Comment: The output result should be in ordered. However, it only sorted the first two runs; sorted the third and fourth runs; fifth and sixth; seventh and eighth. Finally just merge those runs after merged two runs. So the result shows that it only sorted half of the stack. I can't find out the place to fix it. Anyone helps me, please!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few problems in your code. But taking the first issue first, the reason you are not processing all the data is an error in the following line:

```
while(loc < (S1.getQsize()-1))
```

The code inside the following block removes items from `S1` so the size decreases with each iteration.

You could solve this by:

```
int size = S1.getQsize();
while (loc < size - 1)
```

Or (better)

```
while (!S1.emptyCheck)
```

However even if you process all the input data the sorting algorithm still has errors. Perhaps you could fix this problem, investigate further and then come back with a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did what you told me, and it gets better. The runs are separated more accurate. But the final merge still the same.

Comment: @KaixuanChen as mentioned in my answer there are a number of other errors in your code so I'm not surprised the merge isn't working. You will need to post a specific question on an area you are stuck.

Comment: Now the question is the code is only sorting the first loop and put them together. { [3 5 7]+[2 3 5 11 34] will sort; [12] + [10 15 18] will sort; [3 12 17 22] + [12 18 25] will sort; [22 30] } It just sorts once and merge them together. Which the queue still haven't sorted throughout yet. I am wondering if I can add another function to check whether the queue is sorted or not. But still, doesn't work. public boolean OrderCheck(){ int i = firstLoc; boolean check = true; while(check == true && i < lastLoc -1){ if(numArray[i] > numArray[i+1]) check = false; else i++; } return check;}